# I have a code in C but some test cases are not passing

Tags: c

Given names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps friend's names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For each query, print the associated entry from your phone book on a new line in the form name=phoneNumber; if an entry for is not found, print Not found instead.

Note: Your phone book should be a Dictionary/Map/HashMap data structure.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer, name, denoting the number of entries in the phone book.
Each of the subsequent lines describes an entry in the form of space-separated values on a single line. The first value is a friend's name, and the second value is the digit phone number.

After the lines of phone book entries, there are unknown numbers of lines of queries. Each line (query) contains a  to look up, and you must continue reading lines until there is no more input.

***Note: Names consist of lowercase English alphabetic letters and are first names only.***

**Constraints**

1 <= n <= 10^5

1 <= queries <= 10^5

**Output Format**

On a new line for each query, print Not found if the name has no corresponding entry in the phone book; otherwise, print the full and in the format name=phoneNumber.

**Sample Input**

3

sam 99912222

tom 11122222

harry 12299933

sam

edward

harry

**Sample Output**

sam=99912222

Not found

harry=12299933

**Explanation**

We add the following  (Key, Value) pairs to our map so it looks like this:

*phoneBook = {(sam,99912222),(tom,11122222),(harr,12299933)}*

We then process each query and print key=value if the queried key is found in the map; otherwise, we print Not found.

Query 0: sam

Sam is one of the keys in our dictionary, so we print sam=99912222.

Query 1: edward

Edward is not one of the keys in our dictionary, so we print Not found.

Query 2: harry

Harry is one of the keys in our dictionary, so we print harry=12299933.

my code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main() {

        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
         char str[100000];

         typedef struct key_value{
             char name[100000];
             char value[100000];
         }ph;

        ph *pB;

        int i;
        long long n;
        scanf("%lld", &n);

        pB = (ph*) malloc(n * sizeof(ph));

        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
             scanf("%s %s", (pB+i)->name, (pB+i)->value);
         }


        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
            scanf("%s", str);
            if(!(strcmp(str, (pB+i)->name))){
                printf("%s=%s\n", (pB+i)->name, (pB+i)->value);
            }
            else{
                printf("Not found\n");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

where am I wrong please help me. ***There is some problem with constraints mostly I guess.***

Link to the website from where I collected this question is:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem

My code works for the above sample case but there is some hidden test case that is not being passed.

Comment: Both the insert and lookups are not correct. The insert code is wrong because it is not implementing a hash map. The lookup is wrong because it looks for the i-th lookup word in the i-th entry of the table. That is completely wrong because there is no such correlation implemented. For example, in the first given input your code will fail if "harry" is the first lookup because your code looks only in `pB[0]` for that whereas it is in `pB[2]`. Unfortunately I think you need to discard your code and start almost from scratch as there is not much salvagable from what you have.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `pB = (ph*) malloc(n * sizeof(ph));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) the memory allocation functions ( `malloc()` `calloc()` and `realloc()` expect their parameter to be of type `size_t`, however,  `n` has type `long long int` which will cause the compiler to complain.

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include<math.h>`  The posted code does not use anything from the header file: `math.h`.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing that statement.

Comment: OT:  the constraints are: `Constraints

1 <= n <= 10^5

1 <= queries <= 10^5`  however, the names and phone numbers are (relatively) short, so why are the fields: `name` and `value`  declared as 10000 bytes each?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%lld", &n);`  The constraint says that the max number of entries is 10^5 (100000) so why is the variable `n` declared to be a `long long int`?  In general, much better to use `unsigned int`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s %s", (pB+i)->name, (pB+i)->value);`  when using the 'input format conversion specifier `%s`, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field because that specifier always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior

Comment: OT: this is the longest word in the english language `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`  (dont' know about your language) so the name field can be a mere 100 characters and be plenty long enough.  are there any phone numbers that are over 15 digits? No, so the `value` field can be a mere 16 digits/ I.E. 15 digits plus the NUL terminator byte

Comment: the posted code inputs another name to search for every time through the loop.  Not a good idea.  Suggest a nested loop where the outer loop gets the search name and the inner loop searches through all the names for a match

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the desired functionality, except for the hash map
2. minimizes the scope of the index variables `i` and `j`
3. eliminates the 'magic' numbers
4. cleanly compiles
5. properly checks for (and handles) I/O errors
6. leaves the hash map implementation to the OP
7. documents why each header file is included
8. answer completely rewritten per comments
9. reads all the available phone book entries
10. searches all the phone book entries before giving up on answering a query
11. uses dynamic memory allocation (and freeing) due to problems with limited windows stack size

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf(), fprintf()
#include <string.h>  // strcspn()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), free()

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 100
#define MAX_PHONENUMBER_LEN 17

struct key_value
{
    char name[ MAX_NAME_LEN ];
    char number[ MAX_PHONENUMBER_LEN ];
};


int main( void  )
{

    /* Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */


    // get number of entries
    unsigned numEntries;
    if( scanf("%u", &numEntries) != 1)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, 
                 "scanf for number of phone book entries failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    struct key_value *phoneBook = malloc( sizeof( struct key_value ) * numEntries );
    //struct key_value phoneBook[ 10000 ];
    if( ! phoneBook )
    {
        perror( "malloc for phone book entries failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    // read phone book entries

    for( unsigned i = 0; i < numEntries; ++i)
    {
         if( scanf("%99s %16s",
                  (phoneBook+i)->name, 
                  (phoneBook+i)->number) != 2 )
         {
             fprintf( stderr,  
                      "scanf for name and phone number failed\n" );
             free( phoneBook );
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
         }
    }

    // read/process query requests

    char str[ MAX_NAME_LEN ];       
    while( fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin )  )
    {
        // remove trailing newline
        str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        int found = 0;
        unsigned j;

        for( j=0; j < numEntries; j++ )
        {
            if( ! strcmp( str, (phoneBook+j)->name ) )
            {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( found )
        {
            printf("%s=%s\n", (phoneBook+j)->name, (phoneBook+j)->number);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Not found\n");
        }

    }

    free( phoneBook );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your declarations would likely result in StackOverflow on windows with a default 1M stack. `str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\n';` (doesn't remove the `'\n'`). You cannot use any input function correctly without ***checking the return...***. Would you like to make another pass at it?

Comment: Please explain which errors of the OP's source you correct with this.

Comment: @thebusybee,  All the errors, except I did not implement a hash map.  I did not implement the hash map as that was the objective of the exercise, so I left it to the OP to so that.

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect that you [edit] your answer making clear to readers of it, listing the errors the OP made, and how you solved them.

Comment: The introductory statements ( #9 and #10) to my answer highlighted the main problems in the OPs code, that I fixed

Comment: @thebusybee,  If you don't like my answer, then I suggest you post your idea of an answer

Comment: Well, I like your answer, but I feel that it could be better. We are here to help each other, this is not a competition. ;-) Anyway, if you are happy with it, it's OK.